# Export HTML to PDF using JavaScript in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html-to-pdf

I'm having trouble to export HTML into PDF using jsPDF library. I've used the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/0.9.0rc1/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
'#editor': function (element, renderer) {
return true;
}
};

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn').click(function () {
doc.fromHTML($('#content').html(), 15, 15, {
'width': 170,
'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
doc.save('sample-content.pdf');
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<h3>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</h3>
<p>"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" is an English-language pangram—a phrase that contains all of the letters of the alphabet.</p>
</div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<button id="btn">Generate PDF</button>
</body>
</html>
```

It runs very well in IE 11, but it does not run in IE8. I need to export HTML to PDF for IE8. Please suggests me, how can i do that?

Comment: Please give if there is any other solution also ???

Comment: On the web site, it states this: `Browser Compatibility

jsPDF will work in IE6+*, Firefox 3+, Chrome, Safari 3+, Opera. For IE9 and below, we lazily load a Flash shim called Downloadify which enables the files to be downloaded. (Current build does not have IE6-9 shim enabled)`. What error are you getting? Check the console.